# Fixed timezone in weekly javascript timer

Tags: javascript, date, timer

I know nothing about javascript, but I'm trying to obtain a weekly timer that has a fixed timezone so that it shows the same countdown to everyone no matter where they're looking at it from. I've gotten this code from somewhere here:

```
var cday;
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function getSeconds() {
var now = new Date();
var nowtime= now.getTime();
var countdowntime = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),2,0,0);

var dy = 1 ;
var atime = countdowntime.getTime();
var diff = parseInt((atime - nowtime)/1000);
if (diff >0) {
cday = dy - now.getDay();      
}
else {
cday =  dy - now.getDay() -1;
}
if (cday < 0) { cday += 7; }
if (diff <= 0) { diff += (86400 * 7) }
startTimer (diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000); 
tick();
}

function tick() {
var secs = timeInSecs;
if (secs>0)   { 
timeInSecs--; 
} 
else { 
clearInterval(ticker);
getSeconds(); 
 }

var days = Math.floor(secs/86400);
secs %= 86400;
var hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
secs %= 3600;
var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
secs %= 60;
var result = "League update in " + cday +":";
result += ((hours < 10 ) ? "0" : "" ) + hours + ":" + ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins
                + ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs ;
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML =  result;
}
```

And it works perfectly as a weekly timer, but I have no idea how to implement the fixed timezone thing in this. I've seen codes using Date.UTC, but the coding I have to get the time is different so I'm really not sure how I'm supposed to work. :( I've seen codes to get a specific timezone's time, but I need to match it with a weekly timer and I can't seem to find anything that helps.

The time I'd like the countdown to reset at is every Monday 2:00am KST, which would be Sunday 5:00pm UTC, but I seriously don't know how to tell the countdown to only use UTC (or KST, but I believe UTC would be easier).
Can anyone help?

Comment: _"I know nothing about javascript"_ - perhaps you should consider hiring someone.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Uh, no, thanks. I'm fairly sure this is relatively small. And if nothing is ever explained to me, well of course I'll never know anything, right? This isn't something I absolutely can't do. I just need help on it to understand and figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

`utc` variable will give you GMT time in string format

```
var now = new Date()
var utc = now.toUTCString();
```

Comment: But I can't use a string if I want to make a timer? :/

Comment: @Kach I think you want to split each part of time and you can do it now and with `parseInt()` function you can change string to integer